# How to pass Array to SQL Stored Procedure

Tags: sql, arrays, db2-400, rpgle

I am trying to pass arrays to a DB2 stored procedure and I am having trouble.

Here are a few code snippets:

```
create type intArrayType as integer array[];

CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE
array_trial (IN integer_array INTARRAYTYPE)

BEGIN
  SELECT UNNEST(integer_array) FROM sysibm.sysdummy1;
END
```

It compiles, but when I try to call:

```
CALL array_trial(ARRAY[1,2,3]);
```

I am getting a -104 error.

When I try to call from RPGLE, I cannot compile because it does not like the array

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UNNEST is used in the from clause as it creates a [temporary table](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_71/rzajq/rzajqarraytemplist.htm)...

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE
array_trial (IN integer_array INTARRAYTYPE)

BEGIN
  declare c1 cursor with return to client for 
     SELECT * FROM UNNEST(integer_array) as rs;
  open c1;
END;
```

Unfortunately, the ARRAY constructor is currently rather limited.  The [documentation](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_71/db2/rbafzarraycon.htm) specifically says *can only be specified on the right side of a SET variable or assignment-statement.*  So trying to use it directly like so doesn't work.

```
CALL array_trial(ARRAY[1,2,3]);
```

It returns the following message:

```
SQL State: 428H2
Vendor Code: -20441
Message: [SQ20441] Array type not valid where specified. 
Cause . . . . . :   An array type was used but is not allowed in the 
specified context.  Array types can only be used: -- As an argument of an 
SQL or JAVA procedure. -- For an SQL variable declared in an SQL procedure.
-- In a CAST specification in an SQL procedure. 
Recovery  . . . :   Remove the reference to the array type. Try the request again.
```

You can build a driver stored procedure:

```
create or replace procedure mysp
begin
  declare myarray intArrayType;
  set myarray = ARRAY[1,2,3];
  call array_trial(myarray);
end;
```

And call that

```
call mysp;
```

From what I've been able to find so far  An SP with an array parm can be called directly from another SQL procedure or Java...but not RPGLE.